# Need help getting elasticsearch filters to work with laravel

Tags: php, laravel, elasticsearch

I have search filters in Laravel project that work just fine. Now I am trying to make that search more advanced using elasticsearch 7.3.0. I am fairly new in this and need some guidance on how to change current queries in my controller to work in elasticsearch. I looked some tutorials but I can't resolve this in my project. I downloaded and initialized elasticsearch 7.3.0, and I ran it on localhost:9200 and it shows that it works, also I downloaded package  "elasticsearch/elasticsearch": "^7.2", using composer. Also I think I need to make elasticsearch work on my localhost project and not on localhost:9200, so if anyone knows how to make that work it would be awesome. Any help is appreciated, or just some similar examples with guidance in order for me to make it work. Thanks in advance. Here is my code.

CategoryController.php

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Property;
use Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cookie;

class CategoryController extends Controller
{
    public function search()
    {
        if (Auth::check()) {

            $query = Property::query();

            //PROPERTY TYPE!!!
            if (Request::has('propertyType')) {
                Request::get('propertyType');
            }

            $propertyType = Request::input('propertyType');

            if (!empty($propertyType)) {
                $query->whereHas('category', function ($query) use ($propertyType) {
                    $query->whereIn('category', $propertyType);
                });
            }


            // CITY!!!
            if (Request::has('city')) {
                Request::get('city');
            }

            if (Request::input('city')) {
                $query->where('city', Request::input('city'));
            }


            // PRICE
            if (Request::has('min_price')) {
                Request::get('min_price');
            }

            if (Request::has('max_price')) {
                Request::get('max_price');
            }

            if (Request::input('min_price') && Request::input('max_price'))  {
                $query->whereBetween('price', [Request::input('min_price'), Request::input('max_price')]);

            } elseif (Request::input('min_price')) {
                $query->where('price', '>=', Request::input('min_price'));
            } elseif (Request::input('max_price')) {
                $query->where('price', '<=', Request::input('max_price'));
            }


            // SEARCHES
            $results = $query->paginate(6, ['*'], 'searchResults');

        }

        return view('startpage', compact('results', 'request', 'propertyType'));

    }
}
```

startpage.blade.php

```
<form id="searchForm" method="GET" action="/search">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 mb-3">
            <h5 class="text-center">City</h5>
            <input name="city" list="result" id="input" class="form-control" value="{{ isset($request->city) ? $request->city : old('city') }}">
            <datalist id="result"></datalist>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3 mb-6">
            <label>Price</label>
            <input type="number" id="min_price" name="min_price" class="form-control" placeholder="Min Price" value="{{ isset($request->min_price) ? $request->min_price : old('min_price') }}">
            <input type="number" id="max_price" name="max_price" class="form-control" placeholder="Max Price" value="{{ isset($request->max_price) ? $request->max_price : old('max_price') }}">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 mb-6">
            <h5>Property type</h4>
            <div class="d-block my-3 ">
                <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                    <input id="house" name="propertyType[]" value="house" type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" @if (!empty($propertyType) && in_array('house', $propertyType)) checked="checked" @endif>
                    <label class="custom-control-label" for="house">house</label>
                </div>
                <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                    <input id="flat" name="propertyType[]" value="flat" type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" @if (!empty($propertyType) && in_array('flat', $propertyType)) checked="checked" @endif>
                    <label class="custom-control-label" for="flat">flat</label>
                </div>
                <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                    <input id="room" name="propertyType[]" value="room" type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" @if (!empty($propertyType) && in_array('room', $propertyType)) checked="checked" @endif>
                    <label class="custom-control-label" for="room">room</label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row justify-content-md-center">
        <div class="col-md-2 mb-6">
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" type="submit">Search</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <hr class="mb-4">
</form>
```

Comment: Why is your `CategoryController` not extending `App\Http\Controllers\Controller` ?

Comment: @CaddyDZ Sorry, mistake during copying. I edited the post and fixed it. Search form works perfect in laravel. Just need help on how to switch it on elasticsearch :)